# GridView checbox field is Grayed?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView that draws fields from a dataset:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dat = SecurityManager.GetAllGroups();
    GridView1.DataSource = dat;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

One of these is the IsAdministrator property.

It should show up as a checkbox.
It does, but it is grayed out. I want it to be enabled so I can modify it.
From there, I will go through each row and update accordingly.

Is this possible to do? How can I ungray the checkbox?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the [CheckBoxField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxfield.aspx), you can only change the value when in edit mode.  To workaround this, if you want a checkbox for all rows, use the [TemplateField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.aspx), and supply a checkbox in the item template like:

```
<asp:TemplateField ..>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:CheckBox .. Checked='<%# Bind("IsAdministrator") %>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```